# How was this liquidity token locked? I can't find any references to the lockNFT function online?

Tags: nft, uniswap, liquidity-provider

See here https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0e19b17b75dccb9e088c8f00ce8b1d2f4e505e376ee859f9d1d902fb6f36d9bd

> Function: lockNFT(uint256 tokenId)
>
> MethodID: 0x2b7170d0
> [0]:  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007ce13

Can anybody explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

the creator of the midwit token deployed their own nft/lp locker, i believe the original creator of the locker contract is "blurr" (RFD deployer), the contract is verified so you can check what's going on there by reading the code.

basically the nft can't be withdrawn unless 180 days pass after triggerWithdrawal() is called